# How to update SMARTY section after foreach

Tags: php, html, smarty

I have PHP sample like this:

```
<?php
$i=0;
$array1 = $DB->GetAll("select something from table1");
foreach ($array1 as $b)
    {
    $array2 = $DB->GetAll("select something2 from table2");
    $z=0;
    foreach ($array2 as $a)
    {
        $test[$i][data]=$array2[$z][name];
        $i++;
        $z++;
    }
}
$SMARTY->assign('test',$test);
$SMARTY->assign('counter', $i);
$SMARTY->display('test.html');
?>
```

And HTML test.html:

```
{section name=i loop=$test}
<TR>
    <TD>
        {$test[i].data}
    </TD>
</TR>
{/section}
```

The problem is that "test" array is huge and it takes a long time to show it in html page. 
How can I modify code to display result for first row of "foreach ($array1 as $b)" in html, then clear "test" array, and put into it second row, then add it to content of html etc.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How many elements are there in the "test" array? Even with a million rows, generating the HTML wouldn't take more than 2 or 3 seconds (unless Smarty is particularly inefficient). It's displaying them in the browser which will be slow.

Comment: 1000 rows and 5 columns as a result of 60 iterations of "array1". First iteration takes 1 second, 1-2 two seconds, 1-5 one minute, 1-60 15 minutes to display results in html.